# Android background bitmap crop

Tags: android, background, png

I have a background png in my Android application. I would like to support lots of displays, but I have this one obstacle - many displays have many resolutions and many ratios. I would like to make sure my background is displayed properly and make it more ellegant, than just creating 10+ cropped png files in Photoshop.

My idea would be - a fairly large picture imported in the project. The app would find out screen dimensions and simply say starting points(x,y) and ending points, that would "crop" the picture and display it without any deformations.

Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: you wan't to put the image in an ImageView or in a ViewGroup?

Comment: I'd like to add it as a background for a layout. So technically speaking I would like to make it with a drawable **IF POSSIBLE**.

Comment: Ok, when you say background my guess is that you want to put the image over the whole screen? What's wrong with setting the width and height of the layout fill_parent? Also depending on the resolutions and ratios, aren't the XHDPI, HDPI, MDPI and LDPI folders supposed to take care of that?

Comment: Yes you can do that, though you gotta be careful not having phones with small heap handling images that is target large screen sized phones, then you'll end up with out of memory issues.

Comment: @Tooroop yes they are, but I noted in my question that I would like to avoid two working days on croping every single background.

Comment: @Warpzit that is interesting, never thought of it like that. Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: @Michal well a little yes, but my favored approach is to use imageview, set size to match_parent and use scaleType="centerCrop". It gets the job done ;)

Comment: @Warpzit is there a way to set the scaleType to custom? E.g.: I have a picture, that has a focus more to the bottom rather than in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [bitmap.createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29) is the method your looking after. The method simply lets you cut out a defined portion of the bitmap.